# Can "a gerund noun phrase" be used as a secondary verb of the verb "save"?

Tags: ditransitive-verbs

> Jesus saves sinners going to hell

I think here **"save"** seems used as a ditransitive verb taking two objects **"sinners"** and **"going to hell"**, so this sentence can be transformed into **"Jesus saves going to hell for sinners".**
(But it seems like it couldn't a ditransitive verb but just a monotransitive verb if we think of the sentence in this way that there's an omitted preposition as in **"Jesus saves sinners ["from"] going hell"**)

Likewise, can **"a gerund noun phrase"** be used as a secondary object of a ditransitive verb? If so, could you make some sentences as well?

Comment: Why do you assume it's not *Jesus saves sinners **[who are]** going to hell?*

Comment: @JasonBassford see the answer by Fumblefingers (https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/151786/save-you-money-or-save-your-money/151803?__=1883596358#151803). He answered "going to hell" is a secondary object. My first thought was the same as yours, but after reading that answer, I've gotten suspicious  of my thought. And are there any possible sentences in which "a gerund noun phrase" can be a secondary object?

Comment: My point is that it's ambiguous. It could have *either* meaning. You can't tell from the sentence alone what is intended. (Personally, I find *who are* to be the more common interpretation, but it certainly doesn't have to be what is meant.)